# Use a method / function from another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

here's what I'am trying to do, 
I have a Drawer Layout with Frame layout in it and that displays a Fragment, and this Fragment have another Frame layout for Fragment2.

so I want this Fragment2 to use or activate a function in the first Fragment upon button click, because I'm switching Fragment 2 to Fragment 3 and so on and that function is inside the First Fragment.

So MainActivity > MainFragment > (Fragment1, Fragment2, etc).

What I always see is MainActivity > (Fragment1, Fragment2).

So my switching method is inside MainFragment, and Fragment1,2 will use it to replace itself.

and I can't do it. 
I've tried using this code but it doesn't work,

```
bookingFragment = (BookingFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_booking);
```

and error response keep saying im attempting to read a null object.

Main:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    tools:context=".Modules.Activities.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/bg_tan"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/img_logo_header"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="#FFF"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"  />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

First Fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_booking"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_tan"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Modules.Fragments.BookingFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_status"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_book_status_address"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/one_orange"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_book_status_recipient"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/two_gray"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_book_status_package"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/three_gray"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_book_status_address"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingVertical="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:text="Address"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_book_status_recipient"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingVertical="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:text="Recipient"
                android:textColor="@color/hint"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_book_status_package"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingVertical="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:text="Packaging"
                android:textColor="@color/hint"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_below="@id/layout_status"
            android:id="@id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment2:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_tan"
    tools:context=".Modules.Fragments.BookAddressFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_address"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        map:cameraZoom="17"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_above="@id/layout_address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_on_demand"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_white"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:text="On Demand"
            android:textColor="@color/hint"
            android:textAllCaps="false"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_next_day"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_white"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:text="Next Day"
            android:textColor="@color/hint"
            android:textAllCaps="false"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_2_3_days"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_white"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:text="2-3 Days"
            android:textColor="@color/hint"
            android:textAllCaps="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_address"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:text="Single Booking"
            android:textColor="@color/hint"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_circle_pickup_small"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_book_address_pickup"
                android:background="@drawable/border_round_gray"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"
                android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/hint"
                android:textColor="@color/blitz_gray"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:hint="Pick up at"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_circle_deliver_small"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_book_address_deliver"
                android:background="@drawable/border_round_gray"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"
                android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:textColorHint="@color/hint"
                android:textColor="@color/blitz_gray"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:hint="Deliver to"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_book_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"
            android:background="@color/blitz_yellow"
            android:text="Enter recipient details"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: already tried this too:
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()  and 
this.getFragmentManager()

Comment: show your layout xml files

Answer (score 0):

When you are switching to 2nd fragment I am supposing you are doing **replace** instead of **add** in transaction. When you call replace the existing fragment will be in **backstack** and hence all the methods and variable will be destroyed. So when you are calling method declared in **Frag1** from **Frag2**, then as Frag1 doesn't exist in memory anymore, it will return null pointer exception for sure.

If you want to use that function soo much in different fragments try to refactor it to the activity class and then use it by calling

```
getActivity().method_name();
```

Comment: well, the first fragment won't be replaced until I switched fragment using navigation drawer, fragment2 is inside the first Fragment. Fragment got the methods, and fragment2 who is inside it will use it to replace fragment2 with fragment3. DrawerLayout (MainActivity) > Fragment (Booking) > Fragment2 (BookAddress), Fragment3

Comment: hmm.. So you can use this link. I don't know if it will be useful or not bu try it
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i22INe14JUc
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VyyGP_d0Ia8

Answer (score 0):

//in your fragment

```
public void callFunction(){

}
```

//in another fragment

```
MyClassName obj=new MyClassName();
obj.callFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

The most effective way would be the use of BroadcastReceiver, in your first fragment create a receiver

```
public class CustomBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
    OnReceive(Intent intent){
     // do what you need to do
    }
}

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(“filter”);
CustomerBroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver();
```

Register it

```
LocalBroadcastReceiver.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

In fragment2, when you want to activate it all you need to do is

```
LocalBroadcastReceiver.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent);
```

Comment: hmm, i'm not really sure how to implement this one .

Answer (score 0):

Your fragments should not interact with each other directly , this is not recommended. instead they should talk through an intermediate in this cas will be your activity :

so here what you need to do
 - create an interface

```
    public interface Communicator {

    public void switchFragments();
}
```

- now your activity should implement this interface and override the switchFragments() method

- now Create an instance of the Communicator interface in the fragment that should call to change the fragment and than override onAttach in the fragment and assign like this:

  Communicator communicator;
  @Override
  public void onAttach(Context context) {
      super.onAttach(context);

  ```
  try {
      communicator = (YourActivity) context;
  }catch (ClassCastException cce){
      cce.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```

  } 
  now whenever you need to call to change fragment :

  communicator.switchFragments();

inside your activity you can call upon a method inside your first fragment and do what you need to do .

Comment: hmm, here's the thing. 
If I initialize the interface in my MainActivity, I won't be able to control the fragment inside it or use the method of the fragment to the interface, where the fragment switching happens., since it's in the Fragment where all the variables and methods are initialized . 

Fragment = Inside MainActivity , replaced using nav drawer
Fragment2 = Inside Fragment, replaced using fragment2 Button
Fragment3 = Inside Fragment, replaced using fragment3 Button, and so on.

Comment: i think you need to refactor your code with better solution , like move the button into the activity so you can use one button for all of them or something like that , sorry because i couldn't help you more